# Backward Euler method with a cross-product.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, cross-product, simulation

I want to solve the following differential equation with the backward Euler method

$\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}=\frac{\lambda(t)}{\gamma}\times\vec{r}(t)+\frac{\{\vec{r}(t)\times\vec{F}(t)\}\times\vec{r}}{\gamma}$

Which is equivalent to:

$\frac{d\vec{r}(t)}{dt}=\frac{\lambda(t)}{\gamma}\times\vec{r}(t)+\frac{r^{2}\vec{F}(t)}{\gamma}-\frac{\vec{r}(t)\{\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{F}(t)\}}{\gamma}$

I get confused about the cross-product, I don't know what to do with it, should I treat it like a normal product?

Some side information:

This describes the torque on a sphere and the evolution of the vector $\vec{r}$ normal the the sphere.

$\lambda$ is a random Gaussian noise variable

$\vec{F}$ is the force acting on the sphere.

**Update:**

So I can write it as

$\gamma\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\mathrm{d}r_{x}}{\mathrm{d}x}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}r_{y}}{\mathrm{d}x}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}r_{z}}{\mathrm{d}x}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\lambda_{z} & \lambda_{y}\\
\lambda_{z} & 0 & -\lambda_{x}\\
-\lambda_{y} & \lambda_{x} & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
r_{x}\\
r_{y}\\
r_{z}
\end{array}\right]+\left|\vec{r}\right|^{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
F_{x}\\
F_{y}\\
F_{z}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c}
r_{x}\\
r_{y}\\
r_{z}
\end{array}\right]\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
r_{x}\\
r_{y}\\
r_{z}
\end{array}\right]\cdot\left[\begin{array}{c}
F_{x}\\
F_{y}\\
F_{z}
\end{array}\right]\right)
 $

Which gives me seperate equations.

$\dot{r}_{x}=\gamma^{-1}\left(\lambda_{y}(t)r_{z}(t)-\lambda_{z}(t)r_{y}(t)+r^{2}F_x(t)-\left(\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{F}(t)\right)r_{x}\right)$

$\dot{r}_{y}=\gamma^{-1}\left(\lambda_{z}(t)r_{x}(t)-\lambda_{x}(t)r_{z}(t)+r^{2}F_{y}(t)-\left(\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{F}(t)\right)r_{y}\right)$

$\dot{r}_{z}=\gamma^{-1}\left(\lambda_{x}(t)r_{y}(t)-\lambda_{y}(t)r_{x}(t)+r^{2}F_{z}(t)-\left(\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{F}(t)\right)r_{z}\right)$

The Backward Euler scheme:

$y_{k+1}=y_{k}+hf(t_{k+1},y_{k+1})$

Where I need to calculate the following:

$f(y_{k+1})\approx f(y_{k})+\frac{\partial f(y_{k})}{\partial y}(y_{k+1}-y_{k}).$

What is $\frac{d}{dr_x}\left(\vec{r}(t)\cdot\vec{F}(t)\right)r_{x}$?

Comment: At every time step of the Euler Method, just perform the cross-product.  Since I assume these are simply vectors of length three, you can pre-compute the cross-products and assign the proper crossed-elements to the correct rows of $\vec{r}$ for the update.

Comment: OK, so can just write them as separate equations (see update).

Comment: Yep.  Except the dots you have should be replaced by the relevant cross-product terms for each equation.

Comment: I don't think so, I used properties of the triple vector product to rewrite it.

Comment: Indeed.  Sorry, I was focused on the first equation.  Looking at the second equation, you did mean for the $lambda$/$\vec{r}$ cross product to be a matrix/tensor-vector multiply then?

Comment: I just did it so it's easier to write them out in equations for $r_x$, $r_y$, $r_z$. But I'm running into problems with determining the derivative for the r.h.s.

Comment: If we carry out the dot-product, the derivative becomes $\partial_{r_x} [r_x F_x + r_y F_y + r_z F_z] = F_x$.  Also (you may have this, but I want to be sure) remember that $r^2$ has an $r_x^2$ piece to it as well.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention, $F$ is also dependent on the length of $\vec{r}$. So that makes it a lot more difficult.